# Override active_for_authentication? for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Where do I put this to override active_for_authentication?

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && account_active?
end
```

1) Location of file and file name.

2) what the full file would look like.. with, etc...  class something < < devise:something

The original active_for_authentication? method can be found in devise/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb.

thank you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Overwrite the `active_for_authentication?` method in your model [...] — [Source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in)

Thus, if you have a User model you just need to do

```
class User

  def active_for_authentication?
    super && account_active?
  end

end
```